# Is the MODULE.schema.yml required when you define the MODULE.settings.yml?

Tags: 8, database

Is the `MODULE.schema.yml` required when you define the `MODULE.settings.yml`? It seems that it also works when I remove the `MODULE.schema.yml` file from install/schema.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not absolutely required but **strongly** recommended to have one.

By default, Drupal doesn't validate the schema, but it does in tests and [there is an issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2625212) that will enable it if you use the provided example.settings.local.php/development.services.yml. That's why you don't see an error right now when you install, but you'll see it when you write your first test.

It is currently used to ensure the saved configuration has the right data type (e.g. a float and not an integer); not doing that correctly can break stuff and the ability of translating the configuration. More things might follow later, for example a module that generates a settings form.

Answer (score 1):

The settings.yml is only needed when you want to have default values to start with in your config after the module is installed.

Comment: schema.yml has absolutely nothing to do with database tables, you mean hook_schema().

Comment: You are right I got them confused, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

`MODULE/config/install/MODULE.settings.yml` file is not mandatory.

`MODULE.settings.yml` file is basically used for configure default values. and that will only affect when you install module first time.

Two options available for reflect changes in `MODULE.settings.yml`:

1. Uninstall `MODULE` and Install it again!
2. Use `MODULE.install` file and
   `hook_update_N(&$sandbox)`

e.g.
Filename: `MODULE/MODULE.install`

```
    /**
     * Write a line or two here about what the updates are for.
     * This is shown to users on the update.php page.
     */
    function mymodule_update_8001(&$sandbox) {
      $config_factory = \Drupal::configFactory();
      $default_value = 'Test';
      $config_factory->getEditable('MODULE.settings')->set('config_field_key', $default_value)->save();
    }
```

[Reference Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x)

Comment: Do you mean that it is necessary to uninstall the module and install again if the settings.yml updated?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I hope it will help you.